# Spring: OnEnabledEndpointCondition may only be used on @Bean methods that return an @Endpoint or and @EndpointExtension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a [pet project](https://github.com/YashchenkoN/social-network) (social network web application) and I use Spring Cloud to build microservices infrastructure.

I always keep the newest versions of all libraries, so currently I'm updating Spring Boot + Cloud to following versions:

```
springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
springDataVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M4'
```

After I updated versions, my application started failing to start. For instance, when I run tests in `sn-user-service` I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration.environmentWebEndpointExtension
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to extract endpoint id for org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration.environmentWebEndpointExtension
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnEnabledEndpointCondition.getEndpointAttributes(OnEnabledEndpointCondition.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnEnabledEndpointCondition.getEndpointAttributes(OnEnabledEndpointCondition.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnEnabledEndpointCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnEnabledEndpointCondition.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OnEnabledEndpointCondition may only be used on @Bean methods that return an @Endpoint or and @EndpointExtension
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnEnabledEndpointCondition.getEndpointAttributes(OnEnabledEndpointCondition.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnEnabledEndpointCondition.getEndpointAttributes(OnEnabledEndpointCondition.java:89)
    ... 43 more
```

The problem is that I can't find something useful about it in Spring Docs. Is there anybody who faced this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Finchley M5 has been released. It is compatible with Boot 2.0 M7.

At the time of writing, Spring Cloud is not yet compatible with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, even in snapshots. If you want to use Spring Cloud, you'll need to stick with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 for now.

Comment: with 2.0.0.M6 I get this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8667

Comment: that's why I waited for M7

Comment: Finchley M5 has been released

Comment: Tried this... Still have an issue

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Comment: Looks like I have incompatible libraries in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Mean while, if you are ok to sacrifice actuator, try removing it from dependencies. It worked for me.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help